# inteldrmfb api?

Tags: api, linux-kernel, framebuffer

I have a kernel 2.6.31 booting from a USB stick using Intel 915 based KMS to get to graphics mode. It appears to be setting itself to the native resolution and its booting nicely into framebuffer console with a beautiful Tux logo!

Question is, how do I access the inteldrmfb? How do I get it into /dev? Will udev do this for me?

What is the API for programming the framebuffer directly?

Thanks,
FM

Answer (score 0):

Try the directfb library?

edit:
The kernel API is documented in linux/Documentation/fb.  See [Documentation/fb/framebuffer.txt](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/fb/fb/framebuffer.txt;h=fe79e3c8847dc334f479050bb0bc6af5711f868a;hb=HEAD) in the kernel git tree, for starters.  Doesn't seem to have changed for a long time.  Probably still accurate.  Kernel<->user APIs tend to be stable.

http://www.linux-fbdev.org/HOWTO/index.html.  May be useful, but it's probably not as useful as the kernel docs.

Probably, as you say, the library source would be the best reference on how to do things.

If you're not seeing /dev/fb0, even though you have the module loaded, then maybe you need to configure udev for it?  Or just mknod yourself.

Comment: I'm aware of DirectFB.  What I am interested in is documentation on the API that is exported by the framebuffer device, i.e. /dev/fb0 or whatever it is.  This would be the API that something like DirectFB would make use of.  I suppose I could look at the DirectFB code but I was hoping there was some documentation.

Thanks,
FM

Comment: editted with maybe a useful answer, now that I know what you're looking for.